# PROBE_UNKOWN_ACTION as action type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i'm not really sure what is causing this, i have a very simple react app that only has a single reducer (for now), when i try to dispatch an action however it doesn't seem to work? I assume something is wrong with how I created my reducer but i'm not too sure. Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**
it seems my dispatch and everything works, but everytime i switch pages, the state re-initializes to being undefined, instead of working off the current in place state

**store.js**

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import monitorReducersEnhancer from "./enhancers/monitorReducers";
import loggerMiddleware from "./middleware/logger";

import homeReducer, {
  initialSate as homeInitialState,
} from "./home/homeReducer";

const initialState = {
  home: homeInitialState,
};

export const configureStore = () => {
  const middlewares = [loggerMiddleware, thunkMiddleware];
  const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(...middlewares);

  const enhancers = [middlewareEnhancer, monitorReducersEnhancer];
  const composedEnhancers = compose(...enhancers);

  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    home: homeReducer,
  });

  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composedEnhancers);

  return store;
};
```

**homeReducer.js**

```
import { HOME_GET_RECIPE_ID } from "./homeActions";

export const initialSate = {
  id: 0,
};

export default function homeReducer(state = initialSate, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case HOME_GET_RECIPE_ID: {
      return {
        ...state,
        id: action.id,
      };
    }
    default:
      //if there is no recognized action type
      return {
        ...state,
        id: -1,
      };
  }
}
```

**homeActions.js**

```
export const HOME_GET_RECIPE_ID = "HOME_GET_RECIPE_ID"

export const updateSelectedRecipe = (id) => ({
    type: HOME_GET_RECIPE_ID, 
    id
})
```

**homeRedirect.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";

import { updateSelectedRecipe } from "../lib/home/homeActions";

export default function HomeRedirect (props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleChange = () => {
    dispatch(updateSelectedRecipe(props.id)); // will update the id
  };

  return (
    <Link href={props.href} onClick={handleChange}>
      {props.children}
    </Link>
  );
};
```

Comment: Does the following work? `const store = createStore(rootReducer, undefined, composedEnhancers);` Your initial state is already created when the reducer is run the first time.

Comment: unfortunately it still produces the same error

Answer (score 0):

OP here, turns out that the browser was refreshing and thus resetting the state due to the usage of the  tag from material-ui. To prevent an entire window refresh, while redirecting I used the { Link } function previded by react-router-dom, this allowed for a redirect without resetting the state, since it wasn't actually refreshing the browser.